# Amazon Java SDK : creating connection with S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using below code to upload file to S3 bucket.

bucket name is `execute-got-proj`

with this bucket name i observed that SDK is trying to established connection with `execute-got-proj.s3.amazonaws.com`

I believe SDK add `s3.amazonaws.com` in the end to create URI.

however if i give bucket name as `execute-got-proj.vpce-0ec9043449c454d4c8-gt6dduv3.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com`

then it is trying to established connection with `s3.amazonaws.com`.

I couldnt understand the reason. Can anyone please help to understand ?

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region)
                .withCredentials(
                        new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
                .build();
                
.........           
uploadUrl = amazonS3.getUrl(bucketName, compressFileName).toString();
```

Comment: The second almost assuredly is not a valid bucket name.  At any rate, the SDK prefers to use [virtual hosting style requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html) wherever possible.  However, if a bucket has characters in it that are not supported with virtual hosting, the SDK has to fall back to path style access.